# SocketIOClient- Swift : Unable to authenticate socket server

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, authentication, socket.io

I am passing authentication token parameter like below...

```
socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string:"http://localhost:3001")!, config: [.log(true), .forcePolling(true),.connectParams(["Authorisation": kToken])])
```

But it always gives an error....

```
LOG SocketParser: Decoded packet as: SocketPacket {type: 2; data: [login_ack, {
message = "InValid Token";
result = "";
status = error;
}]; id: -1; placeholders: -1; nsp: /}
```

As I think that I am missing some thing to establish authenticated socket connection. So, please guide me where I am lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by my self!

*It was the issue from back end team. They were put some dependencies with the socket call back sender device information details which they are taking from the socket call backs.* ***And the actual problem was ,all the devices and computers were providing their device details but iOS was not giving it from their end with their security protection.So,their validity condition were not satisfying for iOS socket call backs.***

Backend team handled this situation by putting "Other" device type checking at their end.